# SQL multi select with join

Tags: sql, select, join, left-join

I can find a solution for one of my sql statement and I want to ask for your help ;)

Lets imagine that we have table of Athletes and they have to run 100 meters of what ever distance.
after each run the table innserts Run, Name and Time for each run:

```
Run Name  Time[s]
1   Joe     10
2   Joe     11
1   Jim     14
2   Jim     12
```

What I want to do, is to select Run, Name And fastest time, so it this case it would be min(Time).
But when I use Min aggregate function I have to group by all other parameters, so it will return all records...

I have tried this. But it doesn't work:

```
SELECT MIN(Time) AS MinTime, Name AS TimeName
        From Athletes
        group by TimeName
        LEFT JOIN  
        (Select Run, Name, Time From Athletes a)
         On 
         a.Name = TimeName, a.Time = MinTime;
```

Yes, it has syntax error but it's not the main problem, as I udrestand it still won't work.

thanks in advance,
SQL newbie

Comment: do you want to get that athlete who was the fastest among all?

Comment: i need to ask you if u plan to apply min function dynamically or statically..??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your SQL query is all over the place You have an uncessary join and your `group by` is in the wrong place and your `left join` syntax is also incorrect. I scrapped it and rewrote it to use `min()` properly.

```
SELECT run, MIN(Time) AS MinTime,
Name AS Timename
From Athletes
group by TimeName
```

There is no need to run a `join` on the same table and if you knew which columns you needed to `group by`, there is also no need for a where clause.

Tested and working on sqlfiddle. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/13b1a/2

I suggest you read up on what `group by` does and how to `join` tables properly.

As your table grows, if you aren't using any kind of id or key, you can use a more advanced query that does actually involve a subquery:

```
select a.run,
a1.name,
a1.Time
from athletes as a
    ,(select name,
    min(time) as Time
    from athletes
    group by name) as a1
where a.time = a1.Time
and a.name = a1.name
```

There still isn't a reason to use a `join` and the subquery route is the appropriate route to take with your current data set and schema. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/23cb4/23

Comment: Column 'Run' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Although this solution compiles for MySQL, it is not ANSI compliant and the sql fiddle returns some invalid data (the wrong run# is returned for Jim).  The user didn't specify what db vendor...

Comment: Works in sqlfiddle. I would suggest you try it again.

Comment: The sqlfiddle omitted `run` from the select.

Comment: @DMason, updated my answer with a second query taking into account data entered into the table in the future. Also added a new sqlfiddle link.

Comment: Ok.  Our solutions looks awfully similar now.  I'll reverse my down vote it you will.  :)

Comment: Correct, the subquery was pulled out and placed on its own. Placing it within a join is effectively doubling what needs to be done. I have removed my downvote. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
select Run , Name, Time from Athletes a
where Time=(select min(time) 
      from Athletes s 
      where s.Name=a.Name)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM Athletes a
WHERE a.Time = (select min(time) from Athletes a2 where a2.Name = a.Name)
```

Here's an example usage on [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9096a/3)

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT r.Run, r.Name, r.Time 
FROM (SELECT * FROM Athletes ORDER BY Time) r 
GROUP BY r.Name
```

Answer (score -1):

I see `left-join` is one of the tags for you question, but it can be accomplished without it.

```
SELECT *
FROM Athletes a
WHERE a.Time = ( SELECT MIN(a2.Time) FROM Athletes a2 )
```

Note that you may get multiple results from the query if there are two or more runners tied for the fastest time.  Hope this helps.

Here's the query to get the same info, grouped by athlete name:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM #Athletes a
JOIN ( SELECT a2.Name, MIN(a2.Time) Time FROM #Athletes a2  GROUP BY a2.Name) BestTimes
ON a.Name = BestTimes.Name
AND a.Time = BestTimes.Time
```

Comment: This won't work because you're only finding results that match the single minimum time in the whole table, not by athlete

Comment: @DLeh: Perhaps I misunderstood.  But isn't that exactly what the OP is asking for?

Comment: It says "What I want to do, is to select Run, Name And fastest time".  No mention of "group by name".

Comment: His wording is a bit unclear, but he's trying to group by the runners name, so he would want the time per runner.

Comment: @DLeh: Ok, I gave him queries for both.  Not sure which way he wants the data.  I agree, the wording is unclear.

Comment: You don't need a join or a nested select for this query in its current state. It's unnecessary and adds more complexity. Everything he is asking for can be accomplished with the proper `group by` clause.

Comment: @the_pete: But he wants to know which Run# got the fastest time.  Which aggregate function will you choose to guarantee the correct run #?

Comment: @Dmason "fastest time" not fastest run which is why he is `min()`ing on run time not run. The solution presented overshoots the question asked. If I wanted all the information you wanted to give him, I would have restructured my data with, or presented, an id for the table and rewrite my querries appropriately. That said, if he wanted everything you are presenting him, I would use a subquery not a join because that's the proper what to do this.. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/23cb4/21